# In .Net Core. How to render partials without generating an error

Tags: .net-core

I have the following _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container body-content">
  @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/" + Model.Theme + "/_Header.cshtml")

  @RenderBody()

  @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/" + Model.Theme + "/_Footer.cshtml")
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Depending on the value of "Model.Theme", I want to render that partial if it exist. However, if it doesn't exist, then I don't want that partial to render.

How can I prevent "InvalidOperationException" if the Partial doesn't exist?

Please note that I want to test for the partial, not the Model.Theme. The theme will always exist but not all partials will be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fallback to default

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container body-content">
   @if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"Views/" + Model.Name + "/_Header.cshtml"))
   {
      @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/" + Model.Name + "/_Header.cshtml")
   }

  @RenderBody()

   @if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"Views/" + Model.Name + "/_Footer.cshtml"))
   {
      @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/" + Model.Name + "/_Footer.cshtml")
   }
</div>
</body>
</html>
```